# How do you set up a cron job that presses the play music button?

Tags: unix, cron, cron-task

On a mac, the f8/play/pause key allows you to play/pause music from itunes/spotify/etc. How do you set up a cron job that presses that play music button every hour of everyday?

Comment: I suppose you would need to build a robot that has a "finger" that you could move toward the keyboard and direct it to push the button. And then you'd have to write the code to control the robot, etc. The vast majority of `cron` jobs don't have a physical manifestation that is capable of pushing a button...

Comment: I didn't mean literally press the f8 button, but is there a way i could press than button using commands in bash?

Comment: this might work for you: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/63897/can-a-mac-be-programmed-to-simulate-pressing-a-key-at-a-certain-rate-via-softwar

Answer (score 0):

you probably want to create a new script in the mac automator application, which is capable of starting music. Then create a run to run that script.

update: 
you probably want to use the method (http://www.macworld.com/article/1050616/automatoralarm.html) list on that site to create the automator script. And then it will be case of creating a simple cron to start at the time you.